# How to list all the services running with a service account in a server using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I want to update the password of all the services running under one account on multiple servers using powershell. i tried Get-process, Get-WMIObject cmdlets, but these two commands don't have serviceaccount usage. is there a way to update password of all the services running with an account by passing service account,password as parameters to the script.

Answer (score 15):

To get list of services using a particular account you can do:

```
Get-WmiObject "win32_service" -Filter "StartName='domain\\user'"
```

To change the password for these, you can do:

```
Get-WmiObject "win32_service" -Filter "StartName='domain\\user'" | 
%{$_.StopService();$_.Change($null,$null,$null,$null,$null,$null,$null,"blah");}
```

From here: http://www.send4help.net/change-remote-windows-service-credentials-password-powershel-495

Comment: i think this won't work. Get-WmiObject doesn't support StartName

Comment: It works like a charm! accept this answer. it does what you need

Comment: @Ram490 - `StartName` is based on the object returned, which can be of different type base on what you are querying for.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
Function GLOBAL:GET-PROCESSUSER ( $ProcessID ) {

    (GET-WMIOBJECT win32_process  –filter “Handle=$ProcessID”).GetOwner().User

}

$svcs = Get-Process | Select-Object name, starttime, ID

$a = @()


foreach ($svc in $svcs)
{ 
           if ( $svc.name -ne "Idle" -and $svc.name -ne "System")
           {           


           $al = New-Object System.Object
           $al | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name Name -Value $svc.name
           $al | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name Owner -Value ( get-processuser $svc.id)

           $a += $al
           } 
}

$a
```

Edit after comment:

```
$a = (GET-WMIOBJECT win32_service) | ? { $_.startname -eq "domain\\username"} | %{$_.StopService();$_.Change($null,$null,$null,$null,$null,$null,$null,"newpassword");}
```

Comment: Thanks. except starttime, script is listing all the services running with different account. Thanks a lot. But how to update password of the services running with a perticular service account?

Comment: Hi Christian..i just analyzed your script. It lists only the running services on a computer. But when we update password of services running under a service account we need to consider both the running services and not running services also. In this case how can we achieve this with Powershell.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you guys need

```
Get-WMIObject Win32_Service | Where-Object {$_.startname -ne "localSystem" }| Where-Object {$_.startname -ne "NT AUTHORITY\LocalService" } |Where-Object {$_.startname -ne "NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService" } |select startname, name
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah - this seems to be the best approach

```
Get-WMIObject Win32_Service | Where-Object {($_.startname -ne "NT AUTHORITY\LocalService") -and ($_.startname -ne "NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService") -and ($_.startname -ne "localSystem") } `
|select @{ Name = "Service Account " ; Expression = { ( $_.startname ) } }, `
@{ Name = "Service Dispaly Name " ; Expression = { ( $_.name ) } }, StartMode,State, Status | FT -AutoSize
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide a specific answer backed with references. If you have a suggestion or need clarification leave a comment. We have guidelines on [How to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).