# Track down an application pool user account

Tags: asp.net, iis, application-pool

I have a need to find out where an account is being used by an application pool so that I can reset its password. Due to poor documentation, it's unclear if it has been used or where it is. It could potentially be in use by an application pool on any of the servers here, either for a web application or Sharepoint instance. I have looked at IIS on some of the servers I suspected but so far haven't tracked it down.

It's a domain account called `IisUser` that was specifically created for use with IIS. I was hoping there may be a powershell command I could run, or something similar?

If this isn't possible, to avoid breaking any existing applications, what would I need to do in order to create a suitable user for application pools to use? Specifically for querying LDAP servers. I'm running into errors like `System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail)` or `Unable to cast object of type 'System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.GroupPrincipal' to type 'System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal'.` with an application that's trying to talk to LDAP. It works locally but not on a webserver. I found some suggested fixes for this, like changing the apppool to `NETWORKSERVICE` or changing various webconfig settings but nothing worked. I know that the `IisUser` account will work though! I just don't know the password and can't reset it until I know where it is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First of all refer to this post here:**
[How to list all the services running with a service account in a server using Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7338036/how-to-list-all-the-services-running-with-a-service-account-in-a-server-using-po) 
Always use the search on here before posting a question.
**If for some reason the above solution is not working, do the following dirty work below:**
 
1.On your server go to SharePoint Central Administration
2. Go to Monitoring >> Configure diagnostic logging 
3. Choose what type of services you want to log. Careful not to choose all of them because you will flood the log and kill performance.
4. Download a small app called "SharePoint Log viewer" here:
https://sharepointlogviewer.codeplex.com/
It's a free and very useful app.
5. Open one of the logs in the viewer, set filter to "Any Field" and filter with the username IisUser.
If you don't find any records match, load a different log until you do.
6. If you still can't find anything in relation to the user, uncheck your previous selection in Configure diagnostic logging and make a new selection.
7. Go through the logs again. Repeat the process until you find a match.

Comment: I did search but nothing matches my situation. If I knew which Sharepoint server it belonged to (if it's even anything to do with Sharepoint, who knows...) I would be able to locate it easily. My problem is it could be anywhere across ~25 servers and hundreds of applications. The ps command above only has scope on one server it seems.

Comment: Ok, so write a small script and deploy it across your farm. Surely, if you have that many servers / machines, you have the ability to mass deploy anything. Make it so the results are e-mailed to you or written in a log file at a central location, like on a network drive. Use the ps command in that script. Make sure the log files have a naming convention that contain the server name.

Comment: You can use tools for central deployment, like Ansible. https://www.ansible.com/ - I think it has some free features or a demo. You can also use SCCM.